# Chrome is hanging due to my website

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a website and lot of my clients complaining that some time chrome hangs due to my website, cursor moves slowly, it takes a lot of time if I open link or new chrome tab. If I restart the Chrome then it fix problem for some time. I have checked with other websites also and this issue only arrises due to my website.

What is the possible cause/reason for this how can I debug the issue?

My website is built on Ruby On Rails 5.0, I am using Action Cables, React.Js, JQuery.

Comment: How can we possibly guess what's wrong? It's like calling your mechanic and say, "My car doesn't work, please give me a magic fix". You didn't give us _anything_, not a single line of code...

Comment: probably poor coding is to blame - jQuery is probably overused

Comment: @JeremyThille - if it's a Gogomobil then it's probably a broken frex

Comment: Check your server log. E.g: production.log for rails. It could be anything that's running on infinite loop or abused jQuery. Please mention the link to your website.

Comment: Hey @JeremyThille the website is not public, it is private and work on few IPs, thats why I cant provide you the link of my website.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any site link or code, I would recommend you to check out chromes profiling tool to check where the performance issues could come from!

[image]

There you can overview very task that happened within your profiling recording. Look out for long tasks like my `Parse HTML` task.

More about this topic can be found over here: [Google Developer Tooling](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **bullet gem** to increase your application's performance by reducing the number of queries it makes.

Comment: The problem is mostly related to frontend not backend because after my website hangs other website also start hanging.

Answer (score 0):

I second @Kyon, check the performance of your application first. Also check if your server(ROR) instance is enabled to handle concurrency. If the application keeps giving you an Aw Snap error, its most likely that the server is not handling threading correctly. Ruby has many gems like Puma(Ruby/Rack) to enable fast and multi-threaded usage.

Comment: I am using puma, and the problem is mostly related to frontend not backend because after my website hangs other website also start hanging.